# Regex Python: Negative Lookahead delete/keep digits at the beginning

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

The purpose is to keep cardinals and ordinals numbers at the beginning of the string as long as they are immediately before either word `PERFORMANCE` or `SCORE`:

```
#These numbers are kept:
100 SCORE FOR STUDENT
80 PERFORMANCE FOR TEACHER
```

However, if the numbers are at the start and the following word is different, then they should be removed:

```
#These numbers are removed
10095TH 10097TH 179TH SCHOOL ANIVERSARY
11 12 10 SECONDARY LEVELS
100 100 100 100 SCHOOL AGREEMENT
```

The issue I have is when before the word `PERFORMANCE` or `SCORE` there are digits separated by space:

```
#All numbers should be kept
3 10 100 PERFORMANCE
001 10 12345 SCORE
```

I am applying the following regex, but the last section is messy `(?!\s*\d*\s*\d*\s*(?:PERFORMANCE|SCORE)\b)` because currently this is just considering 3 sets of numbers before `PERFORMANCE` or `SCORE` to be kept:

```
(?<=[A-Za-z]\b )([ 0-9]*(ST|[RN]D|TH)?\b)|^(([\d ]+(ST|[RN]D|TH)?)*\b)(?!\s*\d*\s*\d*\s*(?:PERFORMANCE|SCORE)\b)
```

The previous regex works for the following:

```
3 10 100 PERFORMANCE
001 10 12345 SCORE
```

But it will not work if I add an additional set of digits:

```
3 10 100 1 PERFORMANCE
001 10 1 12345 SCORE
```

How can I generalize this rule to include all the set of digits?

Thanks

Comment: You are constantly using extended regex features. Consider installing PyPi regex module to use full power of regexes.

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew, I will consider to install it to use the additional features.

Comment: Well, this time, you can probably get away with a `re` only, try `re.sub(r'^(?=(\d+(?:ST|[RN]D|TH)?(?:\s+\d+(?:ST|[RN]D|TH)?)*))\1(?!\s+(?:PERFORMANCE|SCORE)\b)\s*', '', s)`. See [this Python 3 demo](https://rextester.com/CGMX4567). The regex would look much nicer without hacks with PyPi regex though.

Comment: I have trying to find the way to get working the regex with `11927 242 RD SCORE`. The numbers should be kept because SCORE is in the string even though `RD` is before.

Comment: Just use the `(?!.*\b(?:PERFORMANCE|SCORE)\b)` lookahead, see [this demo](https://rextester.com/WSNV48823). I have a question: can there be numbers inside the string that should be handled in a special way? E.g. `80 PERFORMANCE FOR TEACHER 2020`

Comment: Yes, there are numbers like that and they are deleted in another regex. At this point in regex processing, the number at the end has been removed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206810/discussion-between-juan-perez-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Comment: So, is the answer below fine? It is good if you do not have numbers at all later in the string after the initial ones.

Comment: Thanks a lot @WiktorStribiżew , this solution works very well :)

Comment: Then consider accepting it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
^(?:\d+(?:ST|[RN]D|TH)?\s)+(?=[^\d]+$)(?!PERFORMANCE|SCORE)
```

```
^                       anchor to beginning
(?:                     start non-capturing group
    \d+                 match one or more digits
    (?:ST|[RN]D|TH)?    optionally followed by one of your approved suffixes
    \s                  then a whitespace
)+                      one or more times
(?=[^\d]+$              assert that the rest of the line is number-free (forces the regex to not backtrack to the last number)
(?!PERFORMANCE|SCORE)   assert that the following characters are NOT 'PERFORMANCE' or 'SCORE'
```

Comment: Thanks @Zaelin Goodman, getting almost the right answer. Just the numbers in the following should be kept: `100 SCORE FOR STUDENT   80 PERFORMANCE FOR TEACHER`

Comment: Updated answer to accomodate for this case

Comment: It works great. Thanks for your help @Zaelin Goodman. Just a last question, I have been checking how to Keep the numbers before `PERFORMANCE` and `SCORE` even though there are other words in the string. For instance, `11927 242 RD SCORE`, in this case `RD` is added, but because `SCORE` is there, then the numbers are kept.

Comment: If you want "SCORE" or "PERFORMANCE" to be able to appear anywhere after the numbers, then it just requires a slight change to the negative lookahead to see if the rest of the line CONTAINS those words, rather than begins with them. That regex looks like so `^(?:\d+(?:ST|[RN]D|TH)?\s)+(?=[^\d]+$)(?!.*?(?:PERFORMANCE|SCORE).*?$)`- notice the `.*` has a `?` quantifier - this essentially forces the pattern to match `PERFORMANCE` or `SCORE`, if it's present - we also anchor it to the end of the string with `$` to prevent it matching just the numbers.

Comment: Thank you very much @Zaelin Goodman, it worked perfectly fine.

Comment: Great! Consider marking this as the answer if it's working so we can declutter the "unanswered" queue :)